# multiple sites with htaccess and kept separate

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have 2 sites hosted in the same place: domain1.com and domain2.com

The starting position is that they both point at the root directory.

/root/subdirectory1/ contains the files for domain1.com
/root/subdirectory2/ is the directory for my other site.

domain1.com should pick up the files that are in /subdirectory1/ folder.
domain2.com should pick up the files that are in /subdirectory2/ folder.
I also don't want to be able to access domain1.com/subdirectory2/ because they are separate web sites.
Also any non www URLs should be forwarded to the www. version.

I don't ask for much? Most of what i've seen on the web helps some of this but not all. It seems best not to paste my mashed attempts at this but ask for help with a clean slate.

I have tried the following in the root .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
# Site 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory1/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory1/$1 [L]
# Site 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory2/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory2/$1 [L]
```

And then in the subdirectory1 .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdomain2/(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i still can't get it to work as desired. Please help
(and i don't have access to make virtual hosts with this webspace.)

Comment: This is done with apache virtual host and not with htaccess.

Comment: Actually, the way this site works, it **is** best to paste what you've tried so far since that shows some effort and people are more willing to help correct what you've tried and help you learn why it isn't working vs. creating something out of nothing. As noted by the previous comment, VirtualHost is what you're looking for: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I actually use iPage, and i don't think you can use virtual hosts (or i can't find it).

Comment: Right.. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work 
on domain2.com i get forwarded to www.domain2.com/domain2/
Also I can still go to domain1.com/domain2


RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain2/

# Don't change these line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain2/index.html [L]

Answer (score 0):

If possible, move the domain2 folder outside of the domain1 folder. You'll be glad you did.

Put this in the .htaccess file in the domain1 folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain2/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have a .htaccess file in the domain2 folder add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Depending on what other rules you have for site1, you may not want to inherit them. In that case, just put the first RewriteRule in both .htaccess files.

Now... all of this assumes that your sites are already rendering at domain1.com and domain2.com. If you're trying to get them to render, none of this will help. You'll need to get the domains rendering properly first, which will require vhost setup as mentioned by @N1xx1 and @David. This would need to be done via your control panel software or working with a support person at your host.